# Proper way to test proportions of data points output by a model

Tags: hypothesis-testing, modeling, proportion

I have a dataset with a series $1000$ categoric observations. There are around 250 distinct categories, with $20$ distinct categories comprising around $55 \%$ of the dataset, thus most of them repeat many times.

> My objective is to check whether a model I have, which simulates full datasets like the one I have, is able to accurately depict the **proportion of observations** for these $20$ observations.

With this model I have simulated $200$ series of $1000$ observations, with the intention to have robust mean and standard deviation estimators of the proportion.

Therefore, I have $O_i$, the observed frequency for observation of type $i$; $\bar{M_i}$, the mean frequency of observation of type $i$ in the modeled datasets and $sd(M_i)$, the standard deviation of the frequency across the $200$ modeled series, i.e something like this:

[image]

What would be the adequate approach here?

---

**Further clarification**

The observed dataset would be this way:

A, A, B, C, A, C, A, F, A, D, H, B, ...

And the models generate **stochastic** series (I have produced 200),  e.g.:

A, B, A, A, E, C, A, C, D, D, K, A, ...

There series verify some particular characteristics, but for this particular question I have the objective of assessing whether the proportions of observations are being well captured by the model, es explained in the table above.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a "binary observations" and what it means to "comprise" part of a dataset?  To me, a binary observation has exactly two possible outcomes--maybe three if you allow for missing values--and I just cannot make sense of the "20 distinct observations" from that perspective.

Comment: It's so unclear what you want. As I understood, you have 20 distinct data points which some of them are being repeated, and you want a model to produce those repeating points. If I'm correctly understood you, you should add a new feature as n_repeat and try to model your data. Otherwise, a model cannot have several distinct outputs.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, that was a typo, I meant categorical variables. I have added further clarification to the question, hopefully it is clear now. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @Mehdi I have edited the question to make it more clear. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Instead of "20 distinct observations" would you mean "20 distinct *categories*"? Why do you simulate series of *2000* observations in order to study a dataset of just *1000* observations? What exactly do you mean by "robust," given it doesn't seem to be used in the usual statistical sense (of a procedure that makes minimal distributional assumptions)?

Comment: @whuber I mean capturing the proportions. I can simulate series of any length with the model, what matters is the proportions. Anyway I have changed it to 1000 to make it more clear.

Comment: Doesn't your model specify the expected values of all the categories?  Why do you need a simulation at all?

Comment: @whuber No, it does not specify them. It is a complex model that has several parts. There is autocorrelation in the series, for example.

Comment: That's fine, but this is the first time you have mentioned autocorrelation.  By referring only to frequencies of observations you strongly imply a lack of autocorrelation.  It's beginning to sound like you need to supply details of your situation if you are to have any hope of getting useful answers.

Comment: @whuber I will moll it over. The intention was to simplify the question as much as possible, that is why I left out the autocorrelation, because the sole intention for the purpose of the question is to study the proportions.